# tkinter exe looks old when packed in one-folder exe

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I have a Tkinter code that displays a message box with regular windows 10 icons (window's - warning icon, question mark icon, etc.).
When I run this in a pyinstaller one-**file** .exe, the icons look good.

[image: exit app]

But when I run it in a pyinstaller one-**folder** .exe, the icons look old (like windows 7 icons or something).

[image]

I'm running the same exact code each time, on the same PC.

Comment: one-folder size: 28 MB, including images in the program. one-file size: 11 MB, But not  including images in the same directory. (images size only 624 KB)

Comment: No, they're not, the icons in the question are window's icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the problem was, but I just tried again and it worked without any problems.